# Xcode iOS Bluetooth pairing issues

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, connection

Once a Bluetooth device has been stopped and the connection is lost.  Is it possible for the iPhone to automatically pair to that device once it is turned on again? Instead of manually going into the iPhone settings to connect that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to iOS device. Auto parse is the job of the device you are trying to connect (I am using EA framework, not core bluetooth). I have the same problem on current project. What we did is update firmware that can remember last connection, so next time it will automatically connect to iPhone.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if the device has connected to the iPhone previously and remembered that connection.  The next time the device is in range and switched on – it will automatically connect without the user touching the iPhone?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It is device issue, not iOS issue. Give it a try of updating firmware.